# Open Web page in modal box?

Tags: html, css, popup, modal-dialog

Is this possible? not just html but also a different stylesheet etc while blacking out the rest of the screen?

Thanks for any help.

Ann

Answer (score 7):

Check out [**Colorbox**](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) ([Demo](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html)).  It is a very well put together plugin for [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/).

Using iFrames you are able to load pretty much anything into this modal plugin.  Here is the example code for the demo w/ the iFrame.

**markup**

```
<a class='example7' href="http://google.com">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".example7").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
```

So, you could just change `http://google.com` to `./your-iFrame.html` or whatever and it would load and render that entire page!

Comment: Short note: Colorbox requires jQuery.

Comment: edited answer to reflect jQuery dependence. thx for pointing that out phihag

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [`window.showModalDialog`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html#dialogs-implemented-using-separate-documents)(although this may be implemented as a new window) or implement a modal dialog yourself by loading the page in an `<iframe>` and adding a semi-transparent element whose `z-index` makes it cover the whole document.

Comment: I'd rather not use an iframe + id like it to look nice.

Comment: @Ann Why don't you want to use an `<iframe>`? If it's a webpage you tightly control and know, you may be able to load a part of its content via AJAX into an new `<div>`. Since you can't influence the look of `showModalDialog`, you should consider the latter solution.

Comment: @Ann [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html) is deprecated? Since when? Are you confusing `<iframe>` with `<frameset>` and `<frame>`, which are missing in HTML5 (Good riddance!)? Otherwise, I'd love to hear a source. What could possibly replace them?

Comment: They were deprecated in xhtml/html4 strict, but not in HTML5. @Ann It seems an iframe is exactly what you're asking for. They're not going anywhere soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, load the data into an iframe.  Most modal scripts such as simple modal have this integrated very nicely and only a few options need to be adjusted to make use of it.

Comment: PS. just saw your comments about iframes.  If you don't use an iframe, your likely going to cause yourself many headaches trying to make it work.  An iframe is the only easy solution in your case.