# I Can't Figure Out How To Link an iframe to a Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'd like to link an iframe to a button so I can open the below iframe (iframe/ model window) from clicking on the "keep me posted" button on my site: http://www.aphealthnetwork.com.

**iframe code:**

```
<iframe  width='810px' height='770px' src='https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/WebFormServeServlet?rid=36a8431719e8992d52d2a3fd6413be1b174be02b570ad6d6d795388ce21476a8gid4b981a4b826d7e00d977121adb371cbfd816dda10dd585759e7046fd7a75b6a2'></iframe>
```

**code for the button:**

```
<div class="buttons"><a href="https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/WebFormServeServlet?rid=36a8431719e8992d52d2a3fd6413be1b174be02b570ad6d6d795388ce21476a8gid4b981a4b826d7e00d977121adb371cbfd816dda10dd585759e7046fd7a75b6a2" class="solid">Keep Me Posted!</a> or <a href="index.html#pricing" class="inline scroll">learn more</a></div>
```

I've been searching and searching and can't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: where is it that you are trying to open the iframe? on the same page?

Comment: are you just trying to style a link like a button? I'm not quite following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the end goal is exactly, but if you want to show that iframe in a modal when you click on the button, you could put the iframe in an element for the modal, hide that by default, then show the modal when you click the button. I also added a link to close the model. You might want to adjust the height/width of the modal to fit your needs, too. Or let me know what the end goal is and I can help out with that.

```js
$('.buttons a').on('click',function(e) {
  if ($(window).width() > 820) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modal').show();
  }
});

$('.close').on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#modal').hide();
})
```

```css
#modal {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,0);
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em; right: 1em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons"><a href="https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/WebFormServeServlet?rid=36a8431719e8992d52d2a3fd6413be1b174be02b570ad6d6d795388ce21476a8gid4b981a4b826d7e00d977121adb371cbfd816dda10dd585759e7046fd7a75b6a2" class="solid">Keep Me Posted!</a> or <a href="index.html#pricing" class="inline scroll">learn more</a></div>


<div id="modal">
  <a class="close" href="#">close</a>
  <iframe  width='810px' height='770px' src='https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/WebFormServeServlet?rid=36a8431719e8992d52d2a3fd6413be1b174be02b570ad6d6d795388ce21476a8gid4b981a4b826d7e00d977121adb371cbfd816dda10dd585759e7046fd7a75b6a2'></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you so much for your help :) This is pretty much exactly what I had in mind. Would you also happen to know how to make this responsive as it doesn't work with my iPhone?

Comment: Also, it seams the CSS is off a bit as there is an out of place boarder around the iframe. Any idea on how to fix this by any chance? Thank you so much again Michael, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @chrish83 no problem. Doesn't look like that iframe's contents will be responsive. The insides have a fixed width of 800px. So unless you can control what's in that iframe, it won't be responsive. And re: the border, you can just give `border: 0;` to the iframe, and it will remove that. iframes have borders in most browsers by default.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the border fix! Would there be a way to set it up so when viewed on a mobile device the button would change to a link so I could link the iframe form to a separate page?

Comment: @chrish83 Yeah, a bunch of ways you can tackle that, but I updated the code snippet to check for `$(window).width() > 820` before firing the modal. `820` represents the browser width on the device. I set it to 820 because the width of the code in the iframe wants to be 800px wide, but you can play around with that to whatever works for you.

Comment: Wow, very cool! Works like a charm. Thank you so much again for all of your help. One step closer to finishing up this site :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<input type='button' class='buttons' id='kmp' value='Keep Me Posted' />` or something similar instead... then you could make an output Element `<iframe id='output'></iframe>` and do this, using jQuery:

```
$(function(){

$('#kmp').click(function(){
  $('#output').css('display', 'block').attr('src', 'https://recruit.zoho.com/recruit/WebFormServeServlet?rid=36a8431719e8992d52d2a3fd6413be1b174be02b570ad6d6d795388ce21476a8gid4b981a4b826d7e00d977121adb371cbfd816dda10dd585759e7046fd7a75b6a2');
}

}
```

You also need to make sure that `src` is a full document as well. I see that it's not. I threw in that `.css('display', 'block')` in case you want to start your CSS with `#output{display:none;}`.

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly want?
For responsive modal look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

If you want to display the modal content a similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285955/how-to-display-an-iframe-on-button-click)

If you want to only display the iframe use jquery.

Or look at [Display website in modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537102/open-web-page-in-modal-box)